# CentOS/Ansible - How to fix an error "_ssl.c:602: The handshake operation timed out"

Tags: ansible, centos

I am running an API login task for network device and sometimes I get this error: `"_ssl.c:602: The handshake operation timed out"`. Sometimes it runs and sometimes it gives a handshake error. I recently added RADIUS authentication to network device when using SSH, but API still using local credentials. But would that cause the problem?

Module I am using is the basic URI module and the task looks following:

```
- name: Login to switch using API
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ ansible_host }}/rest/v4/login-sessions"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Accept: "application/json"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    body: {"userName": "{{ ansible_user }}", "password": "{{ ansible_password }}"}
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
    status_code: 201
  register: switch_session
```

Error I am getting looks following:

```
fatal: [test_switch]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "content": "",
    "elapsed": 30,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null,
            "body": {
                "password": "<PASSWORD>",
                "userName": "<USERNAME>"
            },
            "body_format": "json",
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "content": null,
            "creates": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "dest": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "group": null,
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "method": "POST",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "removes": null,
            "return_content": false,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "status_code": [
                "201"
            ],
            "timeout": 30,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "url": "https://<IP_ADDR>/rest/v4/login-sessions",
            "url_password": null,
            "url_username": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [201]: Request failed: <urlopen error ('_ssl.c:602: The handshake operation timed out',)>",
    "redirected": false,
    "status": -1,
    "url": "https://<IP_ADDR>/rest/v4/login-sessions"
```

Comment: Could this be causing the problem?
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19203#issuecomment-395545599

Comment: I'm have the issue around 50% of the time (so it is probably not the ciphers)

Comment: Did you find out the root cause for this?

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Once I `unset` the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables, it worked like a charm!